# Why doesn't window.open(url, name) open in the SAME window with IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

The problem is when calling window.open(url, name) for a specific page, it is always opened in a new window, instead of the **SAME** one. In other words, every time this statement is executed, a new window is opened, while what I want is only ONE new window is opened and all the following calls will open the page in that new window. The name parameter in this javascript statement doesn't work for this case obviously. It only happens with IE11(Couldn't try other versions of IE).

When I tried opening window of my own pages, it worked as expected. But that specific page doesn't. That page is on the same host but out of my control. I don't know what exactly it does. The only thing I know is it relaxes document.domain. But even if I change the domain of the main page to be the same as that page's, it still doesn't work.

Does anybody know what's the root cause?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I encounter the same problem - any news yet?

Comment: @BastianDoeen No, not yet.

Comment: Are you by chance trying to name it "_blank"?  From what I understand, this will make it open in a new window, regardless.

Answer (score -1):

The problem might be due to Internet Explorer settings.

Under Internet Options

1. Click Settings under Tabs
2. Under When a pop-up is encountered:, select Always open pop-ups in a
   new tab
3. Under Open links form other programs in:, select A new tab in the
       current window

Comment: Hi Tejas, it's not about the difference between window and tab.

Answer (score -2):

to do that you want

`window.location` not open

open will open a new window/tab

EG

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com"
```

to navigate to google.com in the same window/tab

Comment: No, I don't want to open the page in the main window. If I do want to do this, window.open(url, '_self'); is also the right command.

Comment: You didn't read what he wanted well enough.  He wanted the first pop-up to be a new window, then everything else after that to go into that window -- not just change the URL of the first, existing window.  It's also `window.location.href = "http://www.google.com"`, not just `window.location`.