# Flex -NavigateToUrl("some url", customname) is opening two tabs in IE11 instead of one tab(in same window)

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer-11, navigatetourl

In flex-3, when I click on a link, a url is called using navigateToURL("someurl",somecustomfixedname).  IE 8,9 and chrome opens that url once in a tab/window(depends on tab settings), if you click the link two or more times same window/tab will reloaded, which is expected.
But in IE 11, on first click a tab/window is opened, second click another tab/window is opened and from third click on wards the second tab/window gets reloaded. I have tried changing the tabs settings in IE11 same as of IE8, it didn't help.  Please suggest some solution.
This following link has similar to my question(but in javascript)"[Why doesn't window.open(url, name) open in the SAME window with IE11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734575/why-doesnt-window-openurl-name-open-in-the-same-window-with-ie11)".  but no solution provided.
I am stuck with this issue, if any one faced this problem kindly suggest a solution.

Comment: Can any one please suggest a solution, or if any more details needed please let me know.

Comment: I was not able to find a cause for the above issue. I have posted in "https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/d20be45a-78f7-4d2a-ba9b-00009860a1a1/ie-11-tab-issue?forum=ieitprocurrentver"  but didn't get any solution yet. if any body could help on this will be helpful.

Comment: Still this Issue not get solved.  Any one have solution for this issue?